# How to extract SCTE104 packet from VANC stream

Tags: video, directshow, video-capture, sdi

my task is to extract SCTE104 packets out of the SDI. from some of the readings i've done, the packets should be in the VANC stream, provided by the **BLACKMAGIC** SDI card.
during run-time, i can spot AFD + CEA708 packets, but no SCTE-104 to be seen nowhere.

i tried reading SCTE-104's manual including SMPTE 2010 - to see which DID + SDID values i should look for, but didn't find it either.

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SMPTE 2010 SDID=0x7 DID=0x41

"The ANC data packet containing ANSI/SCTE 104 Data shall be located in the active line portion of lines in the vertical ancillary space. Data may be located in any lines in the area from the second line after the line specified for switching, as defined in SMPTE RP 168, to the last line before active video, inclusive."

Also the SMPTE 2010 ANC is in the Luma (Y) channel.

Answer (score 0):

regarding the SCTE104 the DID should be 41 and the SDID 7